# multiple ionlist categories in single page using navbar in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

how to display multiple categories in navigation bar in ionics

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="data in response">
<div style="float:left">{{data.product}}</div>
<div style="float:right; color:#387ef5"><span>Rs.</span>{{data.price}}</div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

This is code displaying one table listing for women  products only . Now in this i want to add multiple categories in same page using navigation.

Comment: are you using ionic 1 or 2?

Comment: m using ionic 2

Comment: ionic 2 uses angular 2 and you have `ng-repeat`.. which is of angular 1

Comment: sorry yes i am using ionic 1